# Can't style select box it display different on mobile

Tags: html, css

I have just a simple select box like this one

```
<select>
    <option><a>Navigate To..</a></option>
    <option><a>> Home</a></option>
    <option><a>> About</a></option>
    <option><a>> Blog</a></option>
    <option><a>> Contact Us</a></option>
</select>
```

and I put css with this

```
select {
    margin-top: 50px;
    width: 95%;
    background-color: gainsboro;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 10px !important;
}
```

It display well in desktop but in the mobile phone it doesn't.

I use dolphin and instant browser open it result is the same.

Are there any way to style this select box for view in mobile device

what's it happen please advice.

Comment: It opens fine on my windows phone 8: http://jsfiddle.net/basarat/WLrjt/show/

Comment: You can not put links into options, only text.

Answer (score 2):

use the following for better display in Android phones

`@media only screen and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio:1.5){
/*for low density (ldpi) Android layouts */
}`